# How to reduce the width of the strip?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to reduce the width of the following mobius strip of our Mathematical Society. The resulting image should be more like the following

[image]

The codes below gives:
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 84 65}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\definecolor{dbb}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\definecolor{gbb}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.42}
\definecolor{lbb}{rgb}{0.13, 0.7, 0.67}
\usepackage{libertineotf}

\newcommand{\strip}[1]{%
  \shadedraw[very thick,top color=white,bottom color=gray,rotate=#1] (0:2.8453) ++ (-30:1.5359) arc (60:0:2) -- ++  (90:5) arc (0:60:2) -- ++ (150:3) arc (60:120:2) -- ++ (210:5) arc (120:60:2) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\MoebiusStrip}[3]{%
  \begin{scope} [transform shape]
    \strip{0}
    \strip{120}
    \strip{-120}
    \draw (-60:3.5) node[blue, scale=6,rotate=30] {#1};
    \draw (180:3.5) node[yellow, scale=6,rotate=-90]{#3};
    \clip (-1.4,2.4)--(-.3,6.1)--(1.3,6.1)--(5.3,3.7)--(5.3,-2.7)--cycle;
    \strip{0}
    \draw (60:3.5) node [red,xscale=-6,yscale=6,rotate=30]{#2};
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.2035, rotate=-29]
    \MoebiusStrip{\Large\bf\biolinum VMS}{}{}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you not just put it into a resizebox (or do I misunderstand the question)?

Comment: Oh, I see you are wanting to make the strip narrower not resize the whole thing -- silly me.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't so much make it thinner as make the triangle bigger.  Note: without setting `inner sep=0pt` the node was actually wider than the strip, causing a slight gap at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 84 65}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\definecolor{dbb}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\definecolor{gbb}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.42}
\definecolor{lbb}{rgb}{0.13, 0.7, 0.67}
\usepackage{libertineotf}

\newcommand{\strip}[1]{%
  \shadedraw[very thick,top color=white,bottom color=gray,rotate=#1] (60:3) -- ++ (-30:5) arc (60:0:2)
    -- ++(90:3) arc (0:60:2) -- ++(150:7) arc (60:120:2) -- ++ (210:3) arc (120:60:2) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\MoebiusStrip}[3]{%
  \begin{scope} [transform shape]
    \strip{0}
    \strip{120}
    \strip{-120}
    \draw (-60:4.3) node[inner sep=0pt,blue, scale=6,rotate=30] {#1};
    \draw (180:4.3) node[inner sep=0pt,yellow, scale=6,rotate=-90]{#3};
    \draw (60:4.3) node [inner sep=0pt,red,xscale=-6,yscale=6,rotate=30]{#2};
    \clip (5,0) -- (20:7) -- ++(-60:1) -- ++(-90:3) -- (-15:7) -- cycle;
    \strip{0}
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.2035, rotate=-29]
    \MoebiusStrip{\Large\bf\biolinum VMS}{}{}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mobious]