# Turn a six sides into a 3 sides logo

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to change the codes below so that we have a triangular logo shape?
[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{my polygon/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum size=4cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[top color=black!50!blue,bottom color=blue]
\node[my polygon=6] (a){};
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \xp (initially 6)] in {1,...,6}{ % use `in {1}` to see the edge
  \fill[shade,shading angle={60*(\x+2)}] (a.corner \xp)
     ..controls ++(60*\x:2cm) .. 
     ([shift={({60*(\x+1)+6}:1.5cm)}]a.corner \x) 
     -- (a.corner \x);% Come back such that shading doesn't leak
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong with [John Kormylo's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290976/1952)?

Comment: This one gives better 3D  effect. It is ok for me yet the VMS people want to have this effect.

Comment: Then, it would be nice to make a comment in John's answer mentioning the problem and that you open a new question. It would be also nice make reference to your previous question in this one. As much information you provide more possibilities for a better solution.

Comment: I am sorry for this.

Comment: And where is the code in the question from? (Assuming you didn't write it yourself, as seems likely. It would be strange to come up with this trying to produce the triangle you want, for example.)

Comment: It is from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236209/logo-hexagon-in-the-form-of-a-ribbon

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not put any effort in this question in the past 14 months, and probably will never do. The MWE in the question is entirely @percusse's work